# Tomcat consumes very high CPU usage

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

This is my situation and I do not know what I can check next to solve my problem.

1. I have a Java web application running on tomcat & linux server
2. The application is very slow
3. The `top` command show that the CPU load for the Java process is very high. It reaches more than 1000 percent.
4. the `dstat` command show that the disk write rate is much higher than the read rate

And I can not restart the application :(

What can I do now?

Comment: Why are you not able to restart? (Must the app be always online)?

Comment: You can kill the application and start it again. It sounds to me that your web server has little memory available, like 1 GB RAM.

Comment: Check log files for errors, go fix them; check `free(1)` output to see if you're buried in swap and need to buy more memory; check `dmesg(1)` output for errors, maybe there's something bigger wrong.

Comment: If possible, you could use [jvisualvm](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) to profile the application - it has a CPU Sampling utility that will identify what methods are using the most CPU time.

Comment: yes. I can not restart it now

Comment: jstack <pid>  will give you stack trace, take few samples and see which function is occurring too many times, that should give you some hint.

Answer (score 1):

Well unless you can restart something you can't fix anything.

You've got to analyse what is going on, do we know it's the app that's at fault? [You don't say what else is deployed into the server.] But supposing that it is known to be at fault you need to look at it in some detail.

Busy disk writes is a bit suggestive: is it possible that there's lots of diagnostic trace being output? Or is it possible there's a memory leak and you're getting paging?

There are many performance analysis tools out there, you may need to get into some detailed analysis.